domain blowish blocklist
Am creating a new decentralised application, utilising React Language, and my walletconnect of Phantom and Solflare. Phantom are throwing errors for the domain block. How can I fix them?

Please send an email requesting Blowfish to unflag your website.
review@blowfish.xyz
